# For loops equivalent in R

Tags: python, r, for-loop

I want to convert my python code into R, but cannot get the same result as my python code. I think the problem is with the for loop creation that I cannot do in R. `x` is a string.

Here is the python code:

```py
x <- '5006,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270|905033,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270'
def process_queued_skill_list(x):
  try:
    a=[i.split(',')[0] for i in x.split('|')]
    a=[i for i in a if len(i)<6]
    return '|'.join(a)
  except:
    return 'NA'
```

The code I tried to create in r:

```r
process_queued_skill_list <- function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    a <- sapply(strsplit(x, '|', fixed = TRUE), function(i) i[1])
    a <- a[nchar(a) < 6]
    return(paste(a, collapse = '|'))
  }, error = function(e) {
    return('NA')
  })
}
```

Expected output is '5006'

Comment: This try/except is dangerous and not recommended in either language. This will suppress even syntax errors and other obvious programmer mistakes. Catch only the errors that you expect to encounter.

Comment: Also R has a proper NA value, why return a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you do not have to directly convert a code to the other language. R provides vectorized ways to perform the same. Here is a simple code:

```
process_queued_skill_list <- function(x){
  a <- read.table(text = chartr('|', '\n', x), sep = ',', fill = TRUE)$V1
  paste(a[nchar(a) < 6], collapse = '|')
}

process_queued_skill_list(x)
[1] "5006"
```

---

Note that if you want to exactly match the python code, do:

```
pqsl <- function(x){
    a <- sapply(strsplit(x, "|", fixed = TRUE)[[1]], \(i) strsplit(i,',')[[1]][[1]])
  paste(a[nchar(a)<6], collapse = '|')
}
```

---

A vectorized regex version: To use this in a column you could do:

```
pqsl_vec <- function(x){
     trimws(gsub("(.?(?<=^|[|])\\d{0,5})(\\D|$)|.", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE),,"\\|")
 }
 
x <- c('5006,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270|905033,31',
         '50067,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270|9053,31',
         '500678,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270|9033,31|5')

 pqsl_vec(x)
[1] "5006"       "50067|9053" "9033|5"
```

Comment: what is the fastest way to apply this function to a column of these strings? I am using lapply but it is pretty slow

Comment: @SaraStein use the edited vectorized version

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `read.table()`

If your data is actually as structured as the snippet you posted makes it appear you could read it in as a csv:

```r
# Sample string with some longer than 6 characters and some shorter
# The output should be "5006|9053"
x <- "5006,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270|905361,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270|9053,31,2024-01-17 09:02:03.270"

d <- read.csv(text = gsub("|", "\n", x, fixed = TRUE), header = FALSE)

d
#       V1 V2                      V3
# 1   5006 31 2024-01-17 09:02:03.270
# 2 905361 31 2024-01-17 09:02:03.270
# 3   9053 31 2024-01-17 09:02:03.270

paste(
    d$V1[nchar(d$V1) < 6],
    collapse = "|"
)
# [1] "5006|9053"
```

#### The problem with your code

The key is `strsplit()` is vectorized and returns a list. This is slightly irritating where the input only has one element, as in the first case here, as we need to take element `[[1]]`.

It is useful though where the input has length > 1, as in the second element, as we do not need to `sapply()` but can provide the vector directly to `strsplit()`.

```r
process_queued_skill_list <- function(x) {
    tryCatch(
        strsplit(x, "|", fixed = TRUE)[[1]] |>
            strsplit(",") |>
            lapply(\(x) x[[1]]) |>
            Filter(\(x) nchar(x) < 6, x = _) |>
            unlist() |>
            paste(collapse = "|"),
            
        error = function(e) NA
    )
}

process_queued_skill_list(x)
# [1] "5006"
```

Comment: I think there is a paranthesis error in this

Comment: @SaraStein I don't think there is... I copied and pasted it back into my IDE and it works.

Comment: I get syntax errors when running the function

Comment: the expected output is '5006'

Comment: @SaraStein I changed your input in the second example to give it a more robust test (you are joining but there's only one item in the list). The output will be `"5006"` with your original string. I don't know why you are getting syntax errors.

Comment: for some reason I get syntax error trying to run the process_queued_skill_list funtion, says unexpected >

Comment: @SaraStein are you using R < 4.0.0? If so replace the the native pipe `|>` with the `magrittr` pipe `%>%` and call `library(magrittr)` beforehand. I prefer the `read.csv()` approach anyway through if all your strings have the same format.